# Is Partition Formula wrong when dividing 2 into 2 classes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In basic combinatorics, when dividing a total of N objects into k classes each with $r_k$ objects we have Partition Formula:
$$
\binom{N}{r_1}\binom{N-r_1}{r_2}...\binom{r_k}{r_k}=\frac{N!}{r_1! r_2!...r_k!}
$$

But if you try to divide $2$ into $2$ classes, or $3$ into $3$ classes, the formula gives you $2$ and $6$, but apparently there is only one way to divide it.  But it functions normally when you divide $2$ into $2$ and zero and $3$ into $1$ and $2$.

Since we deduce the Partition Formula from n choose k method, we can see that in the case of dividing $2$ into $1$ and $1$, it first chooses $1$ out of $2$, which has $2$ ways. And then choose the left one. So this process actually arranges the separation orderly. $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are different. 
But in the case of dividing $3$ into $1$ and $2$, we end up with $(a, bc)$, $(b, ac)$ and $(c, ab)$. Not ordered, which is good.

Why? I'm confused. Help me.

Comment: Order of classes matters, but order of objects within a class does not.

Answer (score 1):

> But if you try to divide 2 into 2 classes, or 3 into 3 classes, the formula gives you 2 and 6, but apparently there is only one way to divide it.

This is the case when the classes are identical, i.e., whether your elements $a$ and $b$ in the first class or in the second class is not important. This formula is given for distinct classes, therefore for "2 into 2" case, we have $2! = 2$ such ways and for "3 into 3" case, we have $3! = 6$ such cases.

> But in the case of dividing 3 into 1 and 2, we end up with (a, bc), (b, ac) and (c, ab). Not ordered, which is good.

There is a problem here since formula does not have to count $(bc,a)$, $(ac,b)$, $(ab,c)$ 
when we divide them with $1+2$ and not $2+1$. So, there are $3$ ways to divide them, which is $\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}$, consistent with the formula.

I think the confusion comes from $1+1+1$ and $1+2$ cases. Notice that when we have $3$ classes for $3$ objects, we can permute the objects into classes since the size of the classes are the same for all three. However, in $1+2$ case, we cannot permute them since it restricts us to have $1$ object in the first class and $2$ objects in the second class.

Comment: I think your first point is insightful, that is we should care about the type of class. So, if the type of class matters, we can see the result of partition as a n ordered n-tuple number. Then in the case of 2=1+1 (a,b) and (b,a) are different and thus 2 is the answer. But in the case of 3=1+2, there should be 6 instead of 3 ways, since (a,bc) and (bc,a) are different?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: But that's again inconsistent with the formula since in the case of 3=1+2 it gives us 3 instead of 6...

Comment: But as I said, $1+2$ case is not as same as $2+1$ case since the classes are distinct. When we say $1+2$, we mean class 1 has $1$ object, class 2 has $2$ objects whereas $2+1$ means the vice versa. So in $1+2$, we can't count $(bc,a)$.

Comment: Right. I see what you mean. It helps a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The multinomial coefficient is
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} k\\k_1,\ldots,k_n\end{array}\right) = {k\choose k_1}{k-k_1\choose k_2}\cdots{k-k_1-k_2-\ldots-k_{n-1}\choose k_n},$$
where $k=k_1+\ldots+k_n$ for natural numbers $k_1,\ldots,k_n$, $n\geq 2$. It equals
$$\frac{k!}{k_1!\cdots k_n!}.$$
In particular, if $n=2$, then
$${k\choose k_1,k_2} = {k\choose k_1}{k-k_1\choose k_1}= {k\choose k_1}{k_2\choose k_2} = {k\choose k_1}$$ and also
$${k\choose k_1}={k\choose k-k_1} = {k\choose k_2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your formula is correct, but it does not help answer the question I raised.